# How to create 2 columns in a databinded recyclerview adapter in android java

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am aware of what to do normally by means of a GridLayoutManager but as I've been using Google's GithubBrowserSample (Java) but I am unable to replicate the process using this method.

Tried changing the xml's span count but i am using the androidx version and seemingly doesn't play ball

My Main Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    categoryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(CategoryViewModel.class);
    refreshAndObserve();
    CategoryListAdapter cvAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(dataBindingComponent);
    binding.get().categoryList.setAdapter(cvAdapter);
    adapter = new AutoClearedValue<>(this, cvAdapter);
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class CategoryListAdapter extends DataBoundListAdapter<Category, ListItemCategoryBinding> {
private final androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent;

public CategoryListAdapter(DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent) {
    this.dataBindingComponent = dataBindingComponent;
}

@Override
protected ListItemCategoryBinding createBinding(ViewGroup parent) {
    ListItemCategoryBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.list_item_category,
                    parent, false, dataBindingComponent);
    return binding;
}
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via the XML it seems:

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
app:spanCount="2"
```